# Can't drag & drop UI Elements from storyboard to code in xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, drag-and-drop, storyboard

I am following the instructions of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1

I can't drag and drop the UITextField, UIButton and UILabel to the ViewController code. It just won't drop.

What am I missing to do?

I obviously did not change the name of the view controller and I am just following the steps of the documentation.

Are there any options that I need to check in order to be able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously they say "control-drag" ... I just found out that it means I should press the Ctrl-Button while dragging, and then it indeed works!